# spinner in fragment null pointer

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I want to use spinner in fragment, I have this code but not works, I have `NullPointerException` , what I am doing wrong? thank you.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {




    Spinner spinner_idiomas = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinner_idioma);
    spinner_idiomas.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {


            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), parentView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // your code here
        }

    });



    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.preferencias, container, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Spinner spinner_idiomas = (Spinner)
>   getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinner_idioma);

Use the above if you are looking for a view in the activity. That is not what you want

Change to

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.preferencias, container, false);
  Spinner spinner_idiomas = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_idioma);
  spinner_idiomas.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), parentView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // your code here
    }
    });
 return view;
 }
```